# Changing "Startup and Recovery" settings with BCDEDIT in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, bcdedit

I would like to know if it's possible to change "Startup and Recovery" options from the command-line..

I would like to:

1. Change time to display list of OS to: 1 seconds
2. Enable and set time to display recovery options to: 1 seconds

I've been researching for some time without a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MSDN's [entry](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for BCDEDIT, I found this:

> `/timeout` - Specifies the time to wait, in seconds, before the boot manager selects the default entry.

It does not look like the second option is available from the command line.

I've tried to see using Process Monitor (from SysInternals.com) what's happening when I change those values in the UI, and it's writing to `HKLM\BCD00000000`, but I can't see how that would be changed using BCDEDIT.

Comment: thanks Randolph I was thinking to check with a reg compare tool.. stupid BCDEDIT piece of ---t, MS really messed up on this one.

Comment: I guess you can add it to a very long list of things they could have done differently.